# Data Type conversion with rosbridge

Tags: rosbridge, custom-message

I tried to use ros1_bridge with custom message types. I had one specific value that was an `int32` in ROS1 but a `string` in ROS2 (it was predefined, not my decision), resulting in an error when building ros1_bridge.
In Python or C++, it's pretty easy to convert an integer into a string. Is it possible to directly implement a conversion via rosbridge for such cases?